# REST API on CSR1000v (Amazon EC2 Hosted)

Tags: cisco

I setup an unlicensed (BYOD) CSR1000v on AWS per the steps I outlined on [Deploying Cisco CSR1000v on an AWS EC2 Instance](https://rack.pub/guides/csr1000v-on-aws-ec2).  I configured the REST api per Cisco CSR 1000v Series Cloud Services Router Software Configuration Guide's [Configuring Support for Management Using the REST API](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/routers/csr1000/software/configuration/csr1000Vswcfg/RESTAPI.html) chapter.  The REST api is up/up per the show command.  `user cisco password cisco priv level 15` is also configured.  Lastly, I opened the AWS firewall up to allow everything and can both ping my CSR1000v and can view it via my Web browser.

My issue is that I cannot get the REST api connection started.  It just times out.  Debug shows nothing.  Using CURL, and pasting in the example directly from Cisco IOS XE REST API Management Reference Guide's Introducing the [IOS XE REST API](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/routers/csr1000/software/restapi/restapi/RESTAPIintro.html) chapter:

```
curl -v -X POST https://<my address>/api/v1/auth/token-services -H "Accept:application/json" -u "cisco:cisco" -d "" --insecure -3
```

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cisco CSR 1000v Series Cloud Services Router Software Configuration Guide's [Cisco CSR 1000v Series Cloud Services Router Overview](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/routers/csr1000/software/configuration/csr1000Vswcfg/csroverview.html) chapter says:

> The Cisco CSR 1000v Amazon Machine Image (AMI) does not support
>   management of the router using the REST API.

We'll, isn't that nice...

Comment: No it works try version 16.6.1